# Как запретить создание новых экземпляров класса Django?

Tags: python, django

Хочу в родной админке сделать что-то вроде общих настроек сайта. Если сделать это как обычную модель, то как запретить создавать новые экземпляры этой модели?

Comment: https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo

Comment: Спасибо, испробую

Answer (score 0):

Если запретить создавать именно определённому пользователю или группе пользователей, то можно не давать им разрешений просто, в админке.

Если программно, то нужно переопределить метод save_model класса админки для этой модели.

```
class MyModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass
```